# How can I load a library in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

When I use C++, I can link a library by using a `.a` file or a `.so` file in my Makefile.

But how can I load a library in Common Lisp?

Comment: Which lisp? You need to specify your dialect and implementation. E.g. in Common Lisp you can load a dynamic library (DLL on Windows, .so on Linux) using [CFFI](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you mean by "load a library in Common Lisp".

It could mean "how do I load a Common Lisp library" and in that case, the answer is typically "by referencing your package in the ASDF system definition for your program it is automatically loaded when your system is loaded".

It could mean "how do I load a library written in another language" and in that case, the answer is probably "by using CFFI". That probably requires writing some glue code around data passed to or from the library, to make it more pleasant to use from Common Lisp, though.

Comment: Also [Quicklisp](http://quicklisp.org/)'s `(ql:quickload "library-name")` is usefull this days.

Comment: Which kind of lisp library can I load by ASDF? Is there any tutorial or documents? Thank you.